# insufficient access rights on the entity: Prompt

Tags: permissions, package-install

Installing a managed package in sandbox and getting the error:insufficient access rights on the entity: Prompt

I am a system admin with modify all data. I have checked under setup and am unable to pull up 'in-app guidance'. I also do not see the PROMPT object under setup. Under the system admin profile I do see a unchecked permission 'manage prompts' but I am unable to select it.

What to do?

Comment: try creating a permission set w/ `Manage Prompts` = true and assign to yourself

Comment: Yeah I was able to add it to a permission set and then select it. Still the same outcome. I may have to open a case with support because this is very strange.

Comment: Same issue here - please post your findings when you hear back on your case

Comment: @JasonHartfield Please see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting an answer as I was able to figure it out.

**Log in to your sandbox. From Setup, go to Company Information, and select Match Production Licenses.**

Apparently as it was an older sandbox, some of the licensing had become out of sync.

Comment: I'm having this issue with production trial ORGs that we use for QA and demos; so there is no sandbox to match from. :( I've got a case open with Salesforce.  Hopefully the solution is not to just spin up new trials.

Comment: @JasonHartfield Yes that would be annoying.